# OpenID Connect Discovery

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, discovery

I am reading the [OpenID Connect Discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) specification which states that, when dynamically trying to discover the location of an OpenID Provider, the Relying Part might normalize user's data being authenticated (for example extracting the domain part of user's email) and build an URI to be requested to the host's WebFinger endpoint.

The question is: anybody knows about public Identity Providers which supports WebFinger's endpoint to enable dynamically discovery of OpenID Providers? I was wondering if it does not make sense anymore and if this specification was created to ease the migration from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect.

The most posts I saw talking about OpenID Connect Discovery dates from 2014. So that's why I would like to know if anybody knows about real usage of this specification.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a web-finger request (which is a well known URI resource),
we include the OpenId Provider URI in the href tag of the GET request that we make to retrieve information about the endpoints,jwks_uri,etc (basically a json document retrievable from the OpenId Provider end)

So whatever URI you give( will have to be a registered Identity Provider). Any implementation of OpenId Authorisation Server must implement WebFinger for discovery unless the OpenIdProvider configuration information is already available to the Relying Party.

Popular OpenId Providers are: Google, PingIdentity so on ( for WebFingerSupport, public OpenID provider so on..)